# Построение 3d фигур в реальном времени

Tags: график, графика, 3d

На вход COM-порта поочерёдно поступают координаты вершин поверхности, в совокупности которые образуют облако точек.

Задача - считывать получаемые данные с COM-порта и строить по ним объемное изображение.

Какой язык стоит выбрать для этих целей? В какую сторону копать?
Благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Processing](https://processing.org/), [библиотека](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/index.html) для работы с RS232 и [уроки по 3D](https://processing.org/tutorials/p3d/) графике в Processing.

Comment: Благодарю, почитаю непременно.